# semantic ui typescript correct return type function for dropdown options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui

After sifting through the internet I came to the conclusion I should just ask.

I have a Semantic-UI form in React with TypeScript (strict).

I'm trying to provide options from my rest api to a dropdown (select) in the form (trimmed unnecessary code):

Form[.tsx]:

```
<Form.Select options={()=>{getOptions()}} />
```

And my getOptions function:

```
//I put the DropdownItemProps[] type because I thought it would solve my issue
const getOptions = ():DropdownItemProps[] => {
    let options = new Array<DropdownItemProps>();
    //... restful request
    return (options)
}
```

TypeScript screams at me:

```
Type '() => void' is missing the following properties from type 'DropdownItemProps[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.ts(2740).
FormSelect.d.ts(24, 3): The expected type comes from property 'options' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormSelectProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

I'm not sure why ts detects my function as `'()=>void'` (when I hover the function it clearly detects it as `() => DropdownItemProps[]`). To be honest I'm not even sure `DropdownItemProps[]`  is the correct type I need to return from my `getOptions()` function.

**Edit:** just to be clear, if I change the call to `options={()=>getOptions()}`, `options={getOptions}` or anything similar, I get the same result but instead of `'()=>void'` it admits the the return value is `'()=>DropdownItemProps[]'`.

I basically looked everywhere I could think of, but Semantic-UI's docs don't have anything on TypeScript (which is kinda annoying).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also I wasn't sure if I should've arrow-function'd the call to `getOptions`, but when I didn't and just did `options={getOptions}` ts suggested "Did you mean to call this expression?". And even if I ignored it, it still says: `Type '() => DropdownItemProps[]' is missing the following properties from type 'DropdownItemProps[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.`

Comment: you need to remove the brackets and just write ()=>getOptions() or if you want brackets just add return in front of getOptions() ()=>{ return getOptions()}

Comment: @Jerome it gives me the same thing as I put in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example
seems your getOptions function is not returning an array of objects

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const getOptions = ():DropdownItemProps[]=> {return [{'keyA': 'label A'}, {'keyB': 'label B'}]}


const Test=()=>{
    
    return (

        <Form>
            <Form.Select options={getOptions()} />
            </Form>

    )
}

export {Test}
```

Comment: `options={getOptions()}` would call the function immediately at render no? Isn't it the whole point of putting arrow function?

Comment: but if you do not call the function, which options will be displayed ? that is why the options props is expecting an array of objects... have a look at the definition of the DropDownItemProps. Is is self explained : ```export interface DropdownItemProps extends StrictDropdownItemProps {
  [key: string]: any
}```

Comment: You're correct, I did not think this one through.